# Google maps multiple markers with lng and lat given

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, laravel

I need to display muiltiple markers on my home page on a map. I;am storing each Travel Flyers with a lng and lat in the database, then I display it for each flyer. (Which works fine), but when I display it on my home page with this code, it only displays the last lat and lng that was inserted into the database.

Here is my code:

```html
 <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBaB_9hgeARViVKIT6O1pFKXRCSuYaol2A&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"></script>
    <script>


            jQuery(function($) {
                // Asynchronously Load the map API
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
                document.body.appendChild(script);
            });

            function initialize() {

            @foreach($flyer as $flyers)
                var lat = {{ $flyers->lat }};
                var lng = {{ $flyers->lng }};
            @endforeach

                var map;
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                var mapOptions = {
                    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
                };

                // Display a map on the page
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
                map.setTilt(45);


                // Multiple Markers
                var markers = [
                    [lat, lng ]
                ];




                // Display multiple markers on a map
                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

                // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map
                for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
                    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
                    bounds.extend(position);
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: position,
                        map: map,
                        title: markers[i][0]
                    });

                    // Allow each marker to have an info window
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                        return function() {
                            infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                    })(marker, i));

                    // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
                    map.fitBounds(bounds);
                }

                // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
                var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
                    this.setZoom(14);
                    google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
                });

        }
    </script>
```

As you can see im looping through each flyer. When I go to see the webpage source, it displays through all the LAT and LNG in that foreach, but right here:

```html
                // Multiple Markers
                var markers = [
                    ['', lat, lng ]
                ];
```

it only displays the last lng and lat, do u guys know, maybe I got to insert it into an array or something, I tried many things?
That's what it looks like right now with 1 marker:
[image]

Comment: It only displays the last coordinates because you are overwriting the variable each loop. Anyways, you should not be passing your coordinates with PHP, you should be doing an Ajax call and getting a JSON with all your coordinates, and then doing a JS loop to create your different markers.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! This is what I had to do:

```html
// Multiple Markers
var markers = [
@foreach($flyer as $flyers)
        ['', {{ $flyers->lat }}, {{ $flyers->lng }} ],
@endforeach
];
```